# SQL server: how to show value in next table

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4

I am creating job post application. In my `first table` the columns are

```
jobId
Position
jobDescription
minExp
maxExp
LastDate
InterviewDate
Project
Hiringmanager
interviewer
```

and `second table` contains the skills

```
id
skill
isSlected
```

the problem is that if a person have multiple skills. Then how can i show the first and second table value  in `third table`. like

```
jobId
Position
jobDescription
minExp
maxExp
LastDate
InterviewDate
Project
Hiringmanager
interviewer
skill
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT A.*,
(SELECT ',' + skill FROM [Table2] B WHERE ID = A.JobID ORDER BY skill FOR XML PATH('')) AS Skills
FROM [Table1] A
```

This will give you all the skills as comma separated list

Comment: i am not need comma seprated bcz when i read/select value than i have to write complex logic for that

Comment: You can then go for `JOIN` between the 2 tables. But in that case, you will have multiple records, one for each skill

Comment: Try this:SELECT DISTINCT
jobId
,Position
,jobDescription
,minExp
,maxExp
,LastDate
,InterviewDate
,Project
,Hiringmanager
,interviewer
,ISNULL(skill, 'N/A') AS skill
FROM
 [Table1] A LEFT JOIN [Table2] B
 ON A.jobID = B.Id

Comment: thanks @Abhishek Chaudhary its working.but i not showing value from  tables value into next table

Comment: If you already have a table, you can use the following: INSERT INTO [Table3] (
jobId
,Position
,jobDescription
,minExp
,maxExp
,LastDate
,InterviewDate
,Project
,Hiringmanager
,interviewer
,skill
)
SELECT DISTINCT
jobId
,Position
,jobDescription
,minExp
,maxExp
,LastDate
,InterviewDate
,Project
,Hiringmanager
,interviewer
,ISNULL(skill, 'N/A') AS skill
FROM
 [Table1] A LEFT JOIN [Table2] B
 ON A.jobID = B.Id

Comment: Else, if you don't have an existing table and want this as a one time insert, you can use: SELECT DISTINCT
jobId
,Position
,jobDescription
,minExp
,maxExp
,LastDate
,InterviewDate
,Project
,Hiringmanager
,interviewer
,ISNULL(skill, 'N/A') AS skill
INTO [Table3]
FROM
 [Table1] A LEFT JOIN [Table2] B
 ON A.jobID = B.Id

Answer (score 0):

You can add skills to a different table mapped with `person_id/applied_id`. While showing the person data, join with detail table and you'll get all skills of that person.